# Cannot generate PDF for some specific simplified chinese characters via TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, chinese-locale

I have an existing program (codes) to generate PDF file via TCPDF. It works fine even contain non-English characters in most cases, but now, when the content has either two simplified Chinese characters `喆` (unicode number: 21894) or `旻` (unicode number: 26107), all Chinese characters will be converted to rectangle (invalid character).

I tried to check the uni2cid_ag15.php, and I can find the mapping of those two words and the mapped cids are correct. Is anyone know the reason for converting the Chinese characters incorrectly with that specific character(s)?

References:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources/master/cmapresources_gb1-5/cid2code.txt
https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/fonts/uni2cid_ag15.php

Thanks for the advice in advance.

Comment: Please show your code, especially the lines generating the error, and the actual error messages if there are any, or what is returned vs. what you expected to be returned.  Then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by using new encoding "GB18030" for php function mb_convert_encoding, instead of "GB2312". Those characters can be generated in the PDF without problem.