# TCPDF Font to support Chinese, Japanese along with English with WriteHtml -PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, tcpdf, cjk

I am having problem to print Chinese, Japanese characters in PDF, the PDF is generated by TCPDF.

the only font worked, **kozminproregular** which do not print simple English then,

other than this, I have used, **freeserif**, **FreeSans**, **dejavusans**, **arialuni**.

any font suggesion to print english, and any CJ (chinese, japanese).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a field in which PDF files specify their encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656184/is-there-a-field-in-which-pdf-files-specify-their-encoding)

Comment: Also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784087/cannot-generate-pdf-for-some-specific-simplified-chinese-characters-via-tcpdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737772/tcpdf-encode-chinese-character

Comment: @UmairKhan this would have worked, but the content is getting print in writeHtml ... and also, the text is not only chinese, it has number and english text as well, e.g. GEN - 146 中华人民共和国

Answer (score 0):

One of the best fonts to show English, Spanish, and other languages text, among with Chinese/Japanese languages, is Arial Unicode MS.
Unfortunately, it is not free to use (it requires a license), and there are no bold, italic, and other variants available.

Another great font is the Cybercity one, or the Code2000, or the GNU Unifont.
These may be free to use, but they lack the bold, italic, and any other variant too.